# Diffference between “auswählen” and “auserwählen”?

Tags: difference

Is there any difference between *auswählen* and *auserwählen?*

I was reading a German text for practice, and I came across a sentence like this:

> Er hat Frau X auserwählt.

Can *auserwählen* and *auswählen* be used interchangeably in every context or are there nuances in the meaning of those words that are to be taken into account?

Answer (score 6):

*"Auserwählen"* has the same meaning as *"auswählen"* (*to choose*, *to select*), but it is elevated style. You can use *"auserwählen"* in a religious context (*"das auserwählte Volk"* = *"the chosen people"*) or to refer to a beloved one (*"seine Auserwählte"* = *"the woman he has chosen"*), but you cannot use it to translate *"choose"* in *"Please choose at most three items from this list"*.

Comment: Auch nicht bei einer Partnervermittlung?

Comment: Another example from bible translations: "For many are called, but few are chosen." "Denn viele sind berufen, aber wenige sind auserwählt." (Matthew 22:14)

Answer (score 4):

https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/auserwaehlen

it says: auswerwählen = zu Besonderem bestimmen (which means like "determine for special / to be special)

Answer (score 1):

Du kannst Dinge und Personen *auswählen*. Bei Personen ist die Bedeutung neutral. Also du kannst jemanden beispielsweise für deine Mannschaft oder für eine Kündigung *auswählen*.

*Auserwählen* braucht man in der Regel nur mit Personen(-gruppen) und ist positiv besetzt. Dem Auserwählten widerfährt durch die Auswahl eine besondere Ehre und die auserwählende Person ist in der Regel schon etwas Besonderes (Prinzessin, Gottheit). In der Phrase „der Trainer hat dich für seine Mannschaft *auserwählt*“, klingt eine besondere Ehre oder Aufwertung mit. Verwendet man stattdessen *ausgewählt*, dann bist du nur eine Möglichkeit von mehreren.

Im Gegensatz zu *auswählen* wird *auserwählen* eher selten verwendet.

Comment: Wenn der Trainer jemanden auserwählt klingt da gar nichts mit, weil die Auswahl keine Verbalisierung einschließt. Nur in einer Aussage kann etwas klanglich mitschwingen.

Comment: @userunknown: Richtig und Danke, der Unterschied zwischen auswählen und auserwählen tritt nur in einer Verbalisierung zu Tage, da beide die Tätigkeit einer Auswahl beschreiben. Ich habe meinen Beitrag entsprechend angepasst.

Answer (score 1):

[Auswählen](https://dwds.de/wb/ausw%C3%A4hlen) wird in der Alltagssprache schon genutzt.

Demgegenüber ist "[auserwählen](https://dwds.de/wb/auserw%C3%A4hlen)" seltener und veraltet. Man kann es zwar in einem Buch lesen aber es ist kaum in der Alltagssprache zu hören.